# Positioning vertically .tooltip-inner in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default the arrow is aligned vertically 50% of the `.tooltip-inner` height or from the element to the top of the window:

[image]

But what I really want to do is having the arrow around 20px to the top of the `.tooltip-inner` class or `tooltip's content`:

[image]

I guess it can't be done with .css because the height of the tooltip content is calculated dynamically by javascript. Any help on this? Thanks. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/rod3fnre/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override those with css using the !important.

```
div.tooltip {
    top: 4px !important;    
}

div.tooltip-arrow {
    top: 15px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rod3fnre/5/)

Answer (score 2):

setting margin on top will also work:

```
.tooltip-arrow{margin-top:-13px}
.tooltip-inner{margin-top: 65px}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/rod3fnre/6/)

no **!important** required